# Passing touches through a UIView to a UIScrollView not working

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a view derived from a UIScrollView controller that I use to page through images in a library. That works fine.

I overlayed a UIView on the right side to handle touches for scrolling quickly through the list of images. My problem is that if I pass the touches through to either 'super' or 'nextResponder' they never make it to the UIScrollView object below.

My question is how can I force the UIScrollView below to handle the touches that I don't need to handle? I'm setting a timer for 0.3 seconds that during that time all touches are passed to the UIScrollView to handle. So if the user started a swipe gesture to turn the page, it will happen.

Here's the code for the touchesBegan method:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

// Start a timer to trigger the display of the slider and the processing of events.
touchesTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3 target:self selector:@selector(showSlider:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

// Where are we at right now?
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
lastPage = [self page:currentPoint.y];

// Pass the event though until we need it.
//  [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) 
{
    if (self.nextResponder != nil &&
        [self.nextResponder respondsToSelector:@selector(touchesEnded:withEvent:)]) 
    {
        [self.nextResponder touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I think I might have figured out what could be going wrong. Since the slider on the right side doesn't cover the whole screen, the coordinates from the touches events are not correct. I'm going to try increasing the view size and filtering by touch location.

Comment: There was an excellent presentation at WWDC this year on advanced scrollview techniques.  You may want to spend an hour watching that.  It might be of great help to you in this situation.  The video is available in iTunes under the iTunes U section or from the apple developer site.

Answer (score 1):

I would try using a regular UIViewController rather than a UIScrollViewController and then add the scroll view object where you need it and put the scroll faster view you want on the right side.  This way they are separate and the touches won't get confused.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easier solutions that worked well for me:

In the UIView on top of the UIScrollview make the width and height both 0 (so that the view is no longer technically on top of the UIScrollView) and set clipsToBounds = NO (so that the contents of the view still show up on top of the UIScrollView).

```
 self.OverlayView.clipsToBounds = NO;
 CGRect frame = self.OverlayView.frame;
 self.OverlayView.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, 0, 0);
```

Note that if the UIView contains interactive controls then they will no longer work. You'll need to move it into it's own view above the UIScrollView.