# UITableView inside UITableViewCell not receiving touch events

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiview

So I have a UITableView nested inside a UITableViewCell, like:

- UITableView baseTable

  - UITableViewCell baseTableCell0

    - UITableView subTableView

      - UITableViewCell subTableViewCell
    - UIView subView
  - UITableViewCell baseTableCell1

    - UICollectionView subCollectionView

      - UICollectionViewCell subCollectionViewCell

subView has a UITapGestureRecognizer connected, acts like a button
subTableView and subCollectionView should receives touch events and perform didSelectRowAtIndexPath

On iOS 8 this works fine, but when i'm testing on ios 7 the cells in subTableView and subCollectionView does not receives touch event anymore, the touch event is sent to [baseTableView tableview... didSelectRowAtIndexPath]. However the UITapGestureRecognizer on subView can still receive touch event.

- update: ios 6 has this problem as well, so it only works on ios 8 so far

Answer (score 1):

Use this code  on tab gesture object

```
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

Comment: sorry, i should have mentioned, the tap gesture recognizer is working fine, my problem was that the subTableView and subCollectionView are not receiving touch events

Comment: yes i know bro this property allow to touch on all subview in which you add tab gesture i have same problem and it resolve that ....

Comment: the view with the tap gesture recognizer is not subview of subTableView or subTableViewCell, is subview of baseTableViewCell

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the background color of your UITableView, UITableViewCell and UIView, this way you can see if your child view is not exceeding your parent view, if it is the case your child view is not going to receive touch events. Then either adjust Parent to show child fully or adjust child to remain in the parent boundary.

Hope it helps!

**EDIT:**

May be [passing touch events to subviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719412/how-to-ignore-touch-events-and-pass-them-to-another-subviews-uicontrol-objects) can help.

Comment: thanks for your help, but I checked with view inspector, all subviews are placed within parent views..

Comment: yeah so far i'm using hitTest, it works but looks very unsafe

Comment: how it looks unsafe ?