# InputTransparent in iOS

Tags: ios, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is my XAML.  This `ContentView` is inside an `AbsoluteLayout`, but I don't think that matters.  The idea is to have a frame with a list view, and a darkened background around it.  I want to receive `Overlay_Tapped` if the user clicks outside of the `Frame`.

In iOS, `SpinnerList_ItemSelected` is never called.  Instead, `Overlay_Tapped` is, even if the user clicks **inside** the `Frame`.  In Android everything is fine.

I tried setting `InputTransparent="False"` in the `Frame`, `ListView`, and even the `ViewCell`.  Does not help.  What helps is setting `NumberOfTapsRequired="2"` in the `TapGestureRecognizer`, but that's obviously not my intention.

Help?

```
    <ContentView
        x:Name="SpinnerOverlay"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
        IsVisible="False"
        InputTransparent="False"
        BackgroundColor="{x:Static engine:LmcColor.overlay}">

        <Frame
            OutlineColor="Black"
            Padding="10,10,10,10"
            BackgroundColor="White"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <ListView
                x:Name="SpinnerList"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                HasUnevenRows="False"
                SeparatorColor="Transparent"
                ItemSelected="SpinnerList_ItemSelected">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ContentView
                                    Padding="5,0,5,0"
                                    BackgroundColor="{Binding BackColor}">
                                <Label
                                        Text="{Binding ItemText}"
                                        Style="{StaticResource StandardStyle}"/>
                            </ContentView>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Frame>

        <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Overlay_Tapped"/>
        </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
    </ContentView>
```

Comment: The answer on this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081987/how-do-i-overlay-two-xamarin-forms-layouts-such-that-both-can-receive-touch-inpu looks promising

Comment: I think there is a bug somewhere in there. I encountered this a few days ago. With a frame the InputTransparent property does not seem to do anything.

Comment: It's not just the `Frame`...  I tried putting the `Frame` into an extra `ContentView`, and vice versa, placing a `ContentView` inside the `Frame`.  No bueno.  I can prevent the outer view's Tap processor from being called, but at the "cost" of a call to the *inner* view's Tap processor.  `ItemSelected` is not called no matter what.

The link does look promising, I will certainly try that approach when I have time.

Answer (score 1):

The approach described in [the link suggested by Sharada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081987/how-do-i-overlay-two-xamarin-forms-layouts-such-that-both-can-receive-touch-inpu) does not work for me.  It was designed to make sure that in case of overlaying views, the "lower" one sometimes gets the tap.  I need the opposite: my tap needs to go to the *top* view, but it gets caught and processed by the containing `ContentView`.  Redefining `HitTest()` does not help here.

But trying this approach pushed me into custom renderers, and I was eventually able to solve my issue.  I simply defined a "native" iOS gesture recognizer instead of a `Xamarin.Forms` one.  I would've probably done this earlier if I was more familiar with native iOS development.  I'm more of an Android guy.

Here is the custom renderer code.  `viewWithPoint.Frame.Size.Equals(Frame.Size)` is how I determine that the click was *not* in a smaller subview.  I'm using `VisualElementRenderer<ContentView>` instead of `ViewRenderer` as the latter does not properly process `BackgroundColor`.

```
using CoreGraphics;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MobileCatalog.LmcContentView), typeof(MobileCatalog.iOS.LmcContentViewRenderer))]

namespace MobileCatalog.iOS
{
    /** Custom renderer in iOS is needed for the Overlay Content View:
     * otherwise the "overlay" tap recognizer block taps inside its content */

    public class LmcContentViewRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<ContentView>
    {
        public LmcContentViewRenderer()
        {
            UITapGestureRecognizer recognizer = new UITapGestureRecognizer((g) =>
            {
                if (Element != null)
                    LmcApp.W.ThePage.Overlay_Tapped(Element, null);
            });

            recognizer.ShouldBegin = ((g) =>
            {
                CGPoint point = g.LocationInView(this);
                UIView viewWithPoint = HitTest(point, null);
                return viewWithPoint != null && viewWithPoint.Frame.Size.Equals(Frame.Size);
            });

            AddGestureRecognizer(recognizer);
        }
    }
}
```