# Xamarin Forms InputTransparent=True for Frame isn't working on iOS

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, frame

I have a Frame within my Xamarin Forms App. When I set InputTransparent=True on Android everything works as expected - the tap is handled by the child of the Frame. However on iOS when I set InputTransparent=True the tap is not recognised/lost and fails to handle the tap on the child of the Frame. I am running Xamarin.Forms version 3.6.0.344457 from Nuget.

```
<Frame InputTransparent="True">
     <Button Text="Test" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
</Frame>

private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code or sample so that I can test it on my side?

Comment: Hi there, I can't put in my code because there are a lot of bindings present. But the code snippet that I've added portrays the problem. If you add a break point in the event handler on Android it gets activated and on iOS it doesn't.

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45930037/inputtransparent-in-ios

Comment: I believe this is a bug within Xamarin Forms. The link provided shows a work around, but I was looking for confirmation that this is a bug within Xamarin Forms and if there is a previous version of Xamarin Forms that does work.

Comment: You can add a new issue on github.