# Detecting table cell tap inside of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a UITableView inside of a UICollectionView. When I tap a row in the tableview, it doesn't detect that tap. Instead it's detecting the tap on the collectionviewcell. How do I pass that tap event through to the tableviewcell?

Comment: Check out this question here on stack, I think it's what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834301/ios-forward-all-touches-through-a-view

Comment: I tried that, and it effectively disables scroll on the collectionview. So that won't work for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719412/how-to-ignore-touch-events-and-pass-them-to-another-subviews-uicontrol-objects. Use this to pass it to the subviews.

Comment: I tried that as well, and that didn't work either.