# Transfer Touch event from a UIVew to an UIScrollView

Tags: ios, touch, uigesturerecognizer, gesture, uitouch

I have n `UIScrollView` that fit the whole screen, and a `UIView` displayed in front of it. I would like to transfer touch events from the `UIView` to the `UIScrollView`, such as:

- when I move my finger on the `UIView`, the `UIScrollView` scrolls accordingly (with preserved inertia)
- the UIView may contain buttons, so `userInteractionEnabled = false` is not a good solution
- when I move my finger on the `UIScrollView`, the `UIScrollView` scrolls as usual

If anyone has a solution, please don't hesitate.

Thanks in advance.

[image: picture]

Comment: Try this, seems it is Dup of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488551/how-to-pass-touches-from-uiview-to-uiscrollview

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I put the repo so you can see we did something like you show me, but it didn't work. Perhaps we did something wrong https://bitbucket.org/JPEG06/testgesture/src

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom UIView then implement this delegate:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //return NO to disable click to this UIView and then the click will be forward to the view behind.
    return NO;
}
```

Apparently, you can also try with set the value of .userInteractionEnabled to NO